# Reference .ts file for type check only

Tags: typescript

I'd like to reference another .ts file in a .ts file. In my real project, I only need this for type safety (overriding an inherited member for correct compilation).

My sample:

**Test1.ts:**

```
export class Test1 {

}
```

**Test2.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="Test1.ts" />
export class Test2 {
    abc: Test1; // ERROR: Test1 could not be found
}
```

Is this not possible?
I'd like to avoid importing as it is overhead I don't need in the outputted JavaScript file.

UPDATE: I use Test1 as amd module whose class Test1 is instanciated and injected into an instance of the class Test2 by the underlying framework. This is why i need the export keyword but don't want to directly import the module Type1 - i only need to reference the class to avoid compiler errors and have type safety etc..

Answer (score 4):

**Without using a module loader**

The export keyword at the root level of your file is only relevant if you are using some module pattern (AMD / CommonJS). If you are not the following will work:

*Test1.ts:*

```
class Test1 { // Do not use export

}
```

*Test2.ts:*

```
/// <reference path="Test1.ts" />
class Test2 {
    abc: Test1; // No Error
}
```

However if you do this you are responsible for ensuring that Test1.js is loaded before Test2.js, probably using a script tag.

*NOTE*: If you use a root level export without using a module loader e.g.:

```
export class Test2 {
}
```

The generated javascript:

```
var Test2 = (function () {
    function Test2() { }
    return Test2;
})();
exports.Test2 = Test2;
```

is *wrong* since ***exports*** is not defined anywhere.

**If you *are* using AMD (or CommonJS)**:

Then you *need* to use an import to tell the loader to load the file:

*Test1.ts:*

```
export class Test1 {

}
```

*Test2.ts:*

```
// no reference to other ts required.     
import mod = module("Test1"); // Instead you need to load the module

export class Test2 {
    abc: mod.Test1; // Reference by module 
}
```

***Additionally***

In AMD land each *file **is** a module*. So I prefer not to have a module inside the file since that another level of redirect. i.e. I will need to do `importedFile.module.class` instead of `importedFile.class` where `importedFile` would be what I chose to call the file on import ( I called it `mod` in the given example )

Comment: I have to use both files/modules as AMD modules... The actual import is made by the underlying framework, I just need type safety... You write "If you are using AMD - Then you need to use an import". Is there no way to avoid this constraint?

Comment: I've shown you the error you get in the generated JS. You could potentially declare `exports` as a var to fix the JS error. But you will still not be able to simple `/// reference` the file so the TS issue will remain

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the class in a module so it can be referenced by the outside world through its module.

Example:
**Test1.ts**

```
module SomeModule {
    export class Test1 {
    }
}
```

**Test2.ts**

```
/// <reference path="Test1.ts" />
export class Test2 {
    abc: SomeModule.Test1;
}
```

Optionally you can add Test2 to the same "namespace" and then reference Test1 without specify the module name:

```
module SomeModule {
    export class Test2 {
        abc: Test1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I agree with you about using AMD, the question does not mention this specific need, thats why my answer is straight to the point of how to export and consume another .ts file avoid importing -  as is stated in the question.

According to TypeScript specification "An export declaration declares an externally accessible module member.", thus the exported class should be a member of a module.

Comment: If he does `export class Test2` without using a module loader he will get an `exports not defined` error at runtime.

Comment: Well, it is really weird that my answer has been down voted, considering that it solves the author current situation in the given scenario. If this is the better answer or not is up to the author to decide, but see it being down voted is a bit frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this solution does not work as it does not generate an AMD module for Test1.ts. I need an AMD module for Test1 as well (the underlying framework needs it...).